# using filter function in another filter()

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, filter

I want to have a list of the members who have got something in their shopCart. Please see the example below:

```
users=[
    {"name":"John","age":18,"shopCart":["Python","Csharp","Java"]},
    {"name":"Ellen","age":19,"shopCart":[]},
    {"name":"Eric","age":21,"shopCart":["Python","Java"]},
    {"name":"Jennifer","age":20,"shopCart":[]}
    ]
buyUsers = map(lambda user:user["name"], filter(lambda user:user["shopCart"],users))
print(list(buyUsers))
['John','Eric']
```

The above code works well and gives the answer I want, but I found it in the internet. My question is why is not this possible to use `filter()` instead of `map()`, in the other words I mean why the below code does not give just the names of the users who have something in their shopCart?

```
 buyUsers = filter(lambda user:user["name"], filter(lambda user:user["shopCart"],users))
 print(list(buyUsers))
 [{'shopCart': ['Python', 'Csharp', 'Java'], 'name': 'John', 'age': 18}, {'shopCart': 
 ['Python', 'Java'], 'name': 'Eric', 'age': 21}]
```

Comment: This is because `filter` and `map` have different uses. `filter` is used to select some of the items, where each item selected is unchanged. `map` is used to apply a conversion to every element presented, so the number of items returned is the same as presented, but each item is transformed.

Comment: filter's job is to decide if an item should be kept or removed, map's job is to convert each item somehow.

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation for `filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you found on the internet:

```
buyUsers = map(lambda user:user["name"], filter(lambda user:user["shopCart"],users))
```

says: of all the `users`, find those that have something in `user["shopCart"]`, and then just give me `user["name"]`.

Your modification:

```
buyUsers = filter(lambda user:user["name"], filter(lambda user:user["shopCart"],users))
```

says: of all the `users` find those that have something in `user["shopCart"]`, and then of those, return `users` with a `user["name"]`

In short, your second filter does nothing (in the case of the data you provided) but passes all users through.

The key piece of information you may be missing is that empty items are considered `falsy`. See the sample code below:

```
items = ["a", "", [1], []]
for item in items:
    print(item, bool(item))
```

Output:

```
a True
 False
[1] True
[] False
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` shall always return the items in list that match the condition, so, you will get the whole items like you have got. But, in `map`, you can apply another operation like the extraction of name above.